# error with SetStateAction when filtering data with range slider react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter, slider

I'm new with react/JS and I try to progress.

I have a range slider with 2 values of duration (max and min)

In the backend, duration are stocked in String type. I change the filtration value to request the database through the OnChangeCallback.

But I have 2 errors (the same with minVal):

```
maxVal.toString: (radix?: number | undefined) => string
Argument of type '(radix?: number | undefined) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.ts
DurationFilter.tsx(: Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Another problem is that I use pagination and I don't know how to keep my filter active in the other pages. Do you have suggestions?

```
function DurationFilter({
  durMax,
  durMin,
  onChangeCallback,
}: durMax: string,
  durMin: string,
  onChangeCallback: (filter: { param: string; value: string }) => void) {

  const [maxDuration, setMaxDuration] = React.useState<string>(durMax);
  const [minDuration, setMinDuration] = React.useState<string>(durMin);

  const handleChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    let [minVal, maxVal] = (Array.isArray(newValue)) ? newValue : [newValue, newValue];
    setMinDuration(minVal.toString);
    setMaxDuration(maxVal.toString);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeOutId = setTimeout(
      () => onChangeCallback({ param: ',maxduration', value: maxDuration }),
    );

    return () => clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  }, [maxDuration, onChangeCallback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeOutId = setTimeout(
      () => onChangeCallback({ param: 'minduration', value: minDuration }),
    );

    return () => clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  }, [minDuration, onChangeCallback]);

  return (
    <Box>
        <Slider
          getAriaLabel={() => 'Duration range'}
          onChange={handleChange}
          defaultValue={[parseInt(minDuration), parseInt(maxDuration)]}
        />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default DurationFilter;
```

Comment: You have to change `setMinDuration(minVal.toString);` to `setMinDuration(minVal.toString());` to make your first problem work. For the other problem, what is the setup of the project like? What type of routing are you using?

Comment: Thanks @TimmNL I have this warning "Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string." but it's working (except when I try to go to the next page, it redirect me to the first one).
I didn't code the pagination so I don't really know how to answer your questions, I'm sorry. I'm a beginner ^^"

Comment: But I find these lines: `const setFilter = (key: string, value: string) => {
    if (value || setEmptyValues) {searchParams.set(key, value);}   else {searchParams.delete(key);}
    // RESET PAGINATION IF FILTERS CHANGE
    if (key !== 'offset') {searchParams.delete('offset');}
    useHistory().push({ search: searchParams.toString() });};` So I should investigate there maybe?